# Flash drop and catch game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am doing a flash mini game that a character need to catch item drop down from top.
The problems i am facing are using timer for those 6 items in an array randomly chose and drop down with random x-axis.

```
var PointFood:Array = [Melon1,Honey1,Worm1,Clock1,Poison1,Sling1];
//this is the array of items to drop
time = new Timer(60);
//No idea the timer is with frame or second
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,GenerateItem);
time.start();
function GenerateItem(event:TimerEvent):void
{
axis = Math.round(Math.random()*709.7)+44.45;
//this is the random x axis with my scene width
PointFood[i].x = axis;
PointFood[i].y = 0;
    if(PointFood[i].y < 600.95)
    {
      PointFood[i].y += 10;
    }
}
//here assign the x and y axis
function ItemType(e:Event):Number
{
    i = Math.round(Math.random()*5);
    return i;
}
//this is the random for item in array
```

However the x-axis will be keep changing once the calculation done. Even the items that already exist on screen, their x-axis will also keep changing with the calculation.
Any Solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately we can't really help you if you do not provide some code since your question is a little bit broad.

Comment: forgot about that , wait a minute i will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of dealing with this.
I assume **Melon1**, **Honey1**, ... are instances of your own classes.
Add a public property **positioned** to each of them, like:

```
public var positioned:Boolean=false;
```

At the moment your **ItemType** function just returns a random integer based on the number of objects inside the **PointFood** array.
Let's integrate a check if the random object is already positioned using it's freshly added positioned property:

```
function ItemType(e:Event):Number
        {
            var found:Boolean;

            do
            {
                found = true;
                i = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
                if (PointFood[i].positioned)
                {
                    found = false;
                }
            } while (!found);

            return i;
        }
```

Finally modify the **GenerateItem** function to take the **positioned** property into account - thus just randomize the position if it's **false**:

```
        function GenerateItem(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (PointFood[i].positioned == false)
            {
            axis = Math.round(Math.random() * 709.7) + 44.45;
//this is the random x axis with my scene width
                PointFood[i].positioned = true;
                PointFood[i].x = axis;
                PointFood[i].y = 0;
            }
                if (PointFood[i].y < 600.95)
                {
                    PointFood[i].y += 10;
                }
        }
```

As a side note:

```
time = new Timer(60);
```

means your timer fires every 60 milliseconds - is that the expected behaviour?
Also there might be a little logic problem with your code. As the name GenerateItem implies, I guess this function should just spawn a new object and initialize it's position. Unfortunately it looks like you're abusing this function to do your main game loop as well. I'd recommend splitting this up into two separate functions.

Comment: wow, thanks for that. i will try these and let you know about it.

Comment: this is the first time using flash and got a bit confuse from it

Comment: I hope I didn't confuse you even more now with my talking about classes and stuff. If you get stuck just ask!

Comment: its ok bout it :)

Comment: There is some little problems met after i done those code given.
i create a class (.as) file and the content inside is like
`package  {
 
 public class Pos {

   public var positioned:Boolean=false;
   
   public function SetPost(PointFood:Array)
   {
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
     PointFood[i].positioned = false;
    }
   }

 }
 
}`
The class file is named **Pos** and has been import in my main project with `import Pos`.
But it seems like not function well. 
How if i need to lets those item reach the bottom n re-random again to top?

Comment: I didn't mean that you need a separate class for positioning - just extend your game objects (base) class by a public class
variable *positioned*. If it's working, no need to change it though. If you want to re-randomize your objects simply
revise this condition inside GenerateItem(): `if (PointFood[i].y < 600.95){PointFood[i].y += 10;}` to maybe `if (PointFood[i].y < 600.95){PointFood[i].y += 10;}else{PointFood[i].y=0;PointFood[i].positioned = false;}`

Comment: Yeah, got that and solve the problem ;P
dropping function solved.
Btw there is a small question about the point marking function.
Should i open as a new question or asking here?